# How to make iphone's safari mobile zoom in horizontal mode

Tags: iphone, mobile-safari

So I have made a website built for vertical orientation on the iPhone with the MobileBoilerplate framework.  It's 320px wide and looks great in vertical orientation.

But, when you turn the iPhone sideways, now there are about 100px of white space on the right-hand side.  I'd like to have the viewport zoom in so the 320px design fills up the whole space.

Any suggestions?  Thanks so much!

-Brad

Comment: Just to clarify - you're looking for how to code HTML/CSS to accommodate the iOS mobile safari pinch and tap to zoom features?

Comment: My suggestion is to migrate this to Stack Overflow. This question looks like a coding question to me, and I think it belongs there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
```

This sets up the view port so it expands its width to fill the current screen dimensions.

Comment: This worked!  It was this part that I didn't have already: user-scalable=no